# Does a standalone Java WebSocket server library exist?

Tags: java, html, playframework, websocket

I need to integrate a WebSocket server into my existing Java desktop application. As such, I need an implementation that includes a web server. Even the [Play! Framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaWebSockets) seems like overkill for this case. Do I have any other options?

Comment: Any solution to this old question? I have the same